# WinAPI CreateFile function

Tags: c++, winapi

i have to write CreateFile function in c++
I wrote this, but it didn't work

```
#include <iostream>
#include <windows.h>
#include <string>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    HANDLE hfile = CreateFile(
           ".\temp.txt",                // "\\.\C:" 
           GENERIC_READ, 
           0,
           NULL,
           CREATE_NEW,
           FILE_ATTRIBUTE_NORMAL,
           NULL);

    //if (hFile == INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE) cout << "Unable to create file \n";
    return 0;
}
```

> error C2664: 'CreateFileW' : cannot convert parameter 1 from 'const char [10]' to 'LPCWSTR'

How can I fix this error?

Comment: As well as using a wide string, you'll want to get rid of that tab character `\t`. Use `L".\\temp.txt"`

Answer (score 7):

The error message tells you that it's trying to call `CreateFileW` which is the wide character version of `CreateFile`. You'll need to pass it a wide char literal instead of a regular char one;

```
hfile = CreateFile(
       L".\\temp.txt",               // Notice the L for a wide char literal 
       GENERIC_READ, 
       0,
       NULL,
       CREATE_NEW,
       FILE_ATTRIBUTE_NORMAL,
       NULL);
```

More info [can be found here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/69ze775t(v=vs.110).aspx).

Comment: And how can i write some data into temp.txt ? (changed GENERIC_READ -> GENERIC_WRITE )

Comment: @user1394489 Normally using [WriteFile](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa365747(v=vs.110).aspx), which will write to the file handle CreateFile returns.

Comment: this code compiles without errors, but it doens't create my file ..

#include <iostream>
#include <windows.h>
#include <string>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
 HANDLE hfile;
 char data[] = "some text to write into file";  
 
 hfile = CreateFile(
        L"c:\name.txt",    
        GENERIC_WRITE, 
        0,
     NULL,
        CREATE_NEW,
        FILE_ATTRIBUTE_NORMAL,
     NULL);

 /*
 if (hFile == INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE) 
 { 
  cout << "Unable to create file \n";
  
 }
 */
return 0;
}

Comment: @user1394489 You're not checking the return value, I'm guessing you're getting a security violation since `C:` is not writable unless you're an administrator if you're running at least Vista or newer. Try creating a `C:\Temp` directory and writing to there.

Comment: @user1394489 Also, as noted in the comments above, if you're really using `L"c:\name.txt"` and not `L"c:\\name.txt"`, your filename will contain a line feed `\n` instead of a backslash before name.